# How to configure exim with docker for sendmail

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, sendmail, exim

I am using docker container for emails using this  exim image

https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tianon/exim4/

This works fine if i use smtp host as conatiner name in other website and

Now my joomla site is using sendmail and i am not able to figure out how to link sendmail with exim container

I get this error when try to send mail

`Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail`

thats right because snedmail is not installed within joomla container but how can fix that

Comment: Joomla appears to natively support sending mail via SMTP rather than relying on `/usr/sbin/sendmail`.

Comment: @larsks i did found that but i have seen many extensions rely on send mail to send mails. i have to manually chnage their setting to SMTP . i was thinking if can also fix the sendmail so that if i miss something then sending mails should also work there as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Global_configuration), Joomla has native support for sending mail to an SMTP server.  However, if that won't work (e.g., if you have extensions that ignore Joomla's settings and always try to use a local `sendmail` binary), you can install a sendmail alternative that performs the necessary SMTP transaction for you.

A common solution is [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/), which is often used by [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) users to provide SMTP server for the `mutt` mailer.  The `msmtp` client is command-line compatible, so you can install `msmtp` and then:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/msmtp /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

Provided that you put the appropriate configuration in place, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just about all major MTAs support a "sendmail compatibility mode", and Exim does support that.  The fix is simple.  As root, do:

```
cd /usr/sbin
ln -s exim sendmail
```

Then when your application call **/usr/sbin/sendmail** and passes a message to it on STDIN, exim will parse the commandline options in a sendmail compatibility mode.